# Removing the contents of an arraylist of customized object type based on a specific comparison between the elements of the arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of type RemoveTest, where RemoveTest is a user defined class.
RemoveTest has two properties of String type mId and rmId.
I need to find in the ArrayList, elements(Objects of type RemoveTest) satisfying the below criteria: such that the value of obj1.rmId() is same as obj2.getmId() and then remove both of these elements(obj1 and obj2).

I tried this by writing the below code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class RemoveItr {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<RemoveTest> eleList = new ArrayList<RemoveTest>();
        RemoveTest obj1 = new RemoveTest();
        obj1.setmId("m1");
        obj1.setRmId("");
        RemoveTest obj2 = new RemoveTest();
        obj2.setmId("m2");
        obj2.setRmId("m1");
        RemoveTest obj3 = new RemoveTest();
        obj3.setmId("m3");
        obj3.setRmId("");
        RemoveTest obj4 = new RemoveTest();
        obj4.setmId("m4");
        obj4.setRmId("m3");
        RemoveTest obj5 = new RemoveTest();
        obj5.setmId("m5");
        obj5.setRmId("");
        eleList.add(obj1);
        eleList.add(obj2);
        eleList.add(obj3);
        eleList.add(obj4);
        eleList.add(obj5);
        Iterator<RemoveTest> i = eleList.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            RemoveTest fwdM =(RemoveTest)i.next();
            String fwdId = fwdM.getmId();
            Iterator<RemoveTest> ni = eleList.iterator();

            while(ni.hasNext()){
                RemoveTest revM =(RemoveTest)ni.next();
                String revId = revM.getRmId();
                if(fwdId.equals(revId)){
                    System.out.println("fwdId "+fwdId+"- revId "+revId);
                     i.remove();
                     ni.remove();

                }

            }
        }
    }
}

public class RemoveTest {

    String mId;
    String rmId;

    public String getmId() {
        return mId;
    }
    public void setmId(String mId) {
        this.mId = mId;
    }
    public String getRmId() {
        return rmId;
    }
    public void setRmId(String rmId) {
        this.rmId = rmId;
    }

    }
```

Note: both classes are Public as they were not in the same source file.

But, I got ConcurrentModificationException and I believe it is because, that as I was already in the middle of iterating through the arraylist, and then other loop(iterator) steps in and tries to operate on the same ArrayList.

Is this understanding correct? and If so, how can I resolve this problem and achieve the solution.

Comment: Do you need an `Iterator`? Why can't you just use a regular for loop or enhanced for loop??

Comment: No, Its not necessary that I should use an iterator only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify a collection while iterating over it, except by using `Iterator.remove()`.

This rule implies that you can't use *two* iterators simultaneously and expect `remove()` to work, because calling `remove()` on one iterator will violate the rule for the *other* iterator.

The solution is to collect all the entries that need deleting in a separate `Set`, then after your logic has completed, call `List.removeAll(set)`.

Given this, you don't need iterators at all - just use the foreach syntax:

For a simplistic example:

```
List<RemoveTest> list = new ArrayList<RemoveTest>();
// populate list
Set<RemoveTest> removals = new HashSet<RemoveTest>();
for (RemoveTest i : list)
    for (RemoveTest j : list)
        if (...)
            removals.add(i); // j will get added in another iteration
list.removeAll(removals);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have got your solution..further can you please tell, will using comparator for comparing the elements will be a good approach?

Comment: A Comparator should be used to *order* elements, but you don't need that. You could use a Comparator and test if the comparison result was zero (meaning they have the same sorting rank), but that would be awkward and add unnecessary complication. I think the logic is simple enough that it doesn't need refactoring.

Comment: I have one more question, instead of using Set can't I use an ArrayList..and if not why so?

Comment: You cold use a `List` (notice I didn't say `ArrayList`, more on that later)., but a `Set` is the better choice, because  only unique values (Sets ensure uniqueness by only adding a value if not already contained) are needed for the logic to work. Regarding List/ArrayList, always refer to the abstract type List; only specify the implementation ArrayList when creating one: See [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score -1):

Use CopyOnWriteArrayList instead of ArrayList, it should solve your problem.

Comment: -1 The problem is not a threading issue, so a thread-safe List implementation is not called for. But threading is irrelevant, because using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` would still give the same error as `ArrayList` - it exploding because the list is being updated during iteration.